# CoreBluetooth knowing when advertisement stops

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

`CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` does not seem to have a method for notifying when advertisement stops, unlike its counterpart `-peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising:error:`. Should I assume that the `stopAdvertising` method is synchronous and assume that immediately after it advertisement has stopped?

Comment: No, the `stopAdvertising` method is not synchronous. Easily tested by calling it and then calling `isAdvertising`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You´re right.

`-(void)stopAdvertising` Immediately stops advertising.

This from Apple´s `CBPeripheralManager` class reference.

> Call this method when you no longer want to advertise peripheral manager data.

What might help you (depending of your use case) is to use `isAdvertising` property from the `CBPeripheralManager`.